# How do I open the edge inner page using C#

Tags: c#, microsoft-edge

I want to open edge inner pages, such as "edge://settings", "edge://policy", "edge://versions".

But no matter what I try, I can only open a blank tab.

I don't think this is a very dangerous operation, is there any possibility to open these tabs using C# codes?

Command line I've tried:

```
start msedge "edge://policy"

msedge "edge://policy"

microsoft-edge:edge://policy
```

C# codes I've tried (they seem to work the same as the command line):

```cs
Process.Start("msedge", "edge://policy");

Process.Start("microsoft-edge:edge://policy");
```

supplement:

I'm not trying to read or modify that information on the command line, I just want to help the user open a browser tab such as "edge://settings" or "edge://policy".

I also don’t need any callback on user actions after opening it.

tips: I am using it in a C# language software with administrator, so calling the system API is also allowed, not necessarily the command line.

> I don't speak English well, so I use machine translation. Please forgive me if some words or tone are wrong.

Comment: I don't belive if it's possible ... you can prolly do this via some automation tools  (which would run edge, wait some time and send url + enter)

Comment: You can't show or modify *flags* from the command line. You can use command-line switches to set many of the same settings though. This is common to all Chromium-based browsers. [There's no official list of switches](https://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/run-chromium-with-flags/) as many of them are experimental or intended for browser development only, and browser developers can't make changes once the list is documented. There are informal lists [like this one](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/) though.

Comment: `msedge.exe` isn't in the system path either. In a terminal you have to specify the full path to the binary, `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe` or switch to the application folder. You'll have to do the same with `Process.Start`

Comment: fulll path will not change it ... you cannot open "special tabs" from command line as I wrote in my first comment

Comment: _Using an automated program to perform the simple function of opening a tab sounds like overkill_: This seems like a contradiction. Isn't this exactly what you're attempting to do?

Comment: May I know if you have checked our answers? If there's any question, you can share with us.

Comment: @KendrickLi Thank you very much for answering my question. But... using automation tools to open a browser and enter a URL has too many variables and seems a bit "brute-force". The answers seem to focus on the command line. I wonder if there is any relevant API in C# that can solve this problem?

Comment: @NXY I'm afraid you can only use command line to access URLs (except internal URLs) if automation tools are not an option for you. There's no such C# API for this kind of purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edge internal URLs (edge://xxx) can't be opened from the command line. The best solution is still using automation tools. The key is "having a user typing the URL in the address bar", so automation works.